# Animate an SVG sprite with CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

I’ve got some svg sprites and want to animate them on a website. 
What is the recommended way to use these files?

First, this is my [Hunter (raw covert)](http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.svg) - I got it as eps and converted to svg via indesign.

My entry is to animate it via css by changing the current picture in a keyframes animation.

**Ideas:**

1. I found [this](https://dev.webonomic.nl/unleash-the-power-of-svg-sprites) wonderful blogpost where the current image is selected via anchor
2. Use background position

So I’ve identified the different images in my file, gave them an ID and hidden the others. You can interconnect with #a #b #c ....

[Hunter Image #a](http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.hidden.svg#a)

-> **Problem**: Position on the sprite is still different. I had to change the background position as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/roest/035r0ozq/

```
0% {
    background-image: url(http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.hidden.svg#a);
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url(http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.hidden.svg#b);
  }
```

Entry 2 - use background-position like a normal sprite ...
But something still seems broken.

If you use getspritexy.com with a normal sprite you see within "Generated sprite image" the selection. with my svg you see multiple images ...
Same result in my testFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/roest/4bbnnm9t/

```
0% {
        background: url('http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.svg') no-repeat -83px -15px;
        width: $width;
        height: $height;
      }
      20% {
        background: url('http://elefantenjagdverein.de/server/elephants/hunter/hunter.svg') no-repeat -131px -15px;
        width: $width;
        height: $height;
      }
```

Which of my ideas is the best and how can i get my hunter to animate correctly?

Comment: I tried your fiddle in Chrome and Firefox, but it's not working.  Nothing is displayed.

Comment: yes it's because i used the original width and high generated from getspritexy. If i increase the width you see my image changing position but of course not fitting to the background position anymore. https://jsfiddle.net/roest/4bbnnm9t/1/

Answer (score 2):

To have your frames step from one position to anothe without sliding, you can use `step-end` for the timing function.

```
animation: hunter-animation 2.5s step-end both infinite;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/4bbnnm9t/3/

Now that it steps, you just have to adjust the positions so they are correct.

Comment: Also, there is no need to repeat the background image and height/width everywhere. Just adjust the `background-position`: https://jsfiddle.net/4bbnnm9t/4/

Comment: Great thank you @Sphinxxx. I've updated the fiddle so the animation fits correct. https://jsfiddle.net/roest/4bbnnm9t/5/ - There is still some wiggle in it i can't get out because it's less than a pixel. So the answer for my question is: **You have to find background positions manually. If you resize your image height / width you need to find it again and if it wiggle because the designers work wasn't per millipixel you have to live with it or make a new sprite?**